# Video Ads not showing in YouTube HTML5 Player

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I's experimenting with YouTube HTMl5 Video Player using IFrame Embed. I have successfully created a sample webpage for loading YouTube videos as explained in https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started and I can successfully play youtube video.

However, I came across following situations.

While testing, I can see inline Ads banners and other popups (like subscribe channel, like in facebook, etc) on top of the video. But, I haven't seen any video ads yet. If I check the same video in YouTube website, I can see video ads. I have tried dozens of videos but was out of luck in seeing any Video Ads. Is there something, that I'm missing here or is this some kinda limitation of HTML5 player (as of now).

It would be nice, if somebody can confirm the behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: As of June 2014, video ads now show up in Youtube's HTML5 player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> While testing, I can see inline Ads banners and other popups (like
>   subscribe channel, like in facebook, etc) on top of the video
>   Where did you play the video for testing? On youtube.com or your embedded site?

As of now, ads on videos embedded in 3rd party website is limited and it should happen that no ads is shown in those embedded videos.
Furthermore, HTML5 player has more limitation than Flash player for ads playing, so your situation sounds as expected.