# Youtube iframe API is not showing ads

Tags: http, youtube, youtube-api, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to put an embedded player inside a data url (to paste in the browser url bar) but every time it gets to the ads part the request gets a 400 error (Bad request). I just copied the code from this link, minified it and changed the video id to one with ads: 
  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

```
data:text/html, <!DOCTYPE html><html> <body> <div id="player"></div><script>var tag=document.createElement("script");tag.src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";var player,firstScriptTag=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){player=new YT.Player("player",{height:"390",width:"640",videoId:"LnFsp6iM5dg",events:{onReady:onPlayerReady,onStateChange:onPlayerStateChange}})}function onPlayerReady(e){e.target.playVideo()}firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag,firstScriptTag);var done=!1;function onPlayerStateChange(e){e.data!=YT.PlayerState.PLAYING||done||(setTimeout(stopVideo,6e3),done=!0)}function stopVideo(){player.stopVideo()}</script> </body></html>
```

When running it on a node server I also get these errors, so I can't get it to play ads either:
http://jsfiddle.net/7gyxgaqj/1/

What can I do? Am I doing anything wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: no ads is surely a bonus?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon The thing is youtube's terms say we must not "modify, interfere with, replace, or block advertisements placed or served by YouTube or by YouTube API Services including in API Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or YouTube players;", and I don't know if that counts...

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110271) wherein it that *ads on videos embedded in 3rd party website is limited and it should happen that no ads is shown in those embedded videos.* Also based from this [page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en), you will automatically be opted into showing ads on embedded videos if you've associated your YouTube and AdSense accounts and have enabled your videos for embedding.  Note that embedded videos will honor the same ad enablement settings as videos on youtube.com.

Comment: did u get a solution on this?